# Execution Custom Query in Laravel

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I try to execution query like this

```
@type = 'hobby'

IF @type = 'hobby'

    BEGIN

        SELECT m.id, m.name, m.address, p.name as parentName into #tempPeople from man m join parent p = m.parentId = p.id

        SELECT h.id, h.manId, h.hobbyName, h.timeSchedule, tp.name, tp.parentName from hobby h 
        join #tempPeople tp on h.manId = tp.id

        drop table #tempPeople

    END

ELSE 

  BEGIN  

        SELECT m.id, m.name, m.address, p.name as parentName into #tempPeople from man m join parent p = m.parentId = p.id

        SELECT gf.id, gf.manId, gf.name, gf.address, tp.name, tp.parentName from girlFriend gf
        join #tempPeople tp on gf.manId = tp.id

    END
```

my laravel code like this

```
 public static function getManControl($type)
    {
        $sql = "
        declare @type varchar(100)

        @type = '".$type."'

        IF @type = 'hobby'

            BEGIN

                SELECT m.id, m.name, m.address, p.name as parentName into #tempPeople from man m join parent p = m.parentId = p.id

                SELECT h.id, h.manId, h.hobbyName, h.timeSchedule, tp.name, tp.parentName from hobby h 
                join #tempPeople tp on h.manId = tp.id

                drop table #tempPeople

            END

        ELSE 

          BEGIN  

                SELECT m.id, m.name, m.address, p.name as parentName into #tempPeople from man m join parent p = m.parentId = p.id

                SELECT gf.id, gf.manId, gf.name, gf.address, tp.name, tp.parentName from girlFriend gf
                join #tempPeople tp on gf.manId = tp.id

            END
        ";

        $result = DB::select($sql);
        return $result;
    }
```

the results of the above code, get an exception like this

PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.

how to run that query in laravel ?? what should i use ?

Comment: Could you show the laravel code? Would be easier to help

Comment: @Collin i was update it bro

Comment: Try putting `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of your `$sql`. Laravel's probably getting confused by the row counts coming back from your `#tempPeople` creations.